# jackson json with hibernate: jackson-module-hibernate usage

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I am relatively new to jackson and am trying to import json into mysql through hibernate 3.3 and vice verse and having problem about jackson-module-hibernate

From its github site:

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new HibernateModule());

and  I think I need to change it to :

mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate4Module());

However, there is a type mismatch :

mapper.registerModule expects org.codehaus.jackson.map.Module interface,
but the Hibernate4Module extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module.

Therefore, I get compilation error. Can anybody help me on this? Some example
code about how to do this will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is difference between Jackson 1.x and Jackson 2.0. Hibernate 4 module is only available for Jackson 2.0 (Hibernate 3 versions were available for both 1.x and 2.0).

Comment: Thanks.  We upgraded to Jackson 2.1.0 and were able to get the hibernate module working.  Appreciate the tip.